# How to set default date(today's date) of ion-datetime?

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework

So this is my html code, i would like to set the default date of the datepicker to today's date. How should i go about doing this?

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Date</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD MMMM YYYY" pickerFormat="DD MMMM YYYY" [(ngModel)]="request.date" (Value)="myDate" ></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign today's date value like this -

```
this.request.date = new Date().toJSON().split('T')[0];
```

Comment: Is there a way to use a second ngmodel or smth else if I don't want to use the current ngmodel that I have?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I know I have to assign this code: new Date().toJSON().split('T')[0]; to the ngModel. Is there anyway to have another ngModel so that I can tie that code to that ngModel instead ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Ultimately you will get the same result.